# Why my program is going in the infinite loop?

Tags: java

I am trying to compile and execute C , C++ and Java codes taken as argument to a Java file and then check that the generated solution is correct or not as most of the website judge the solutions.Please anybody can tell me why my code is going in infinite loop and no out put is coming in **file_name_output.txt**. My other all files are correct as i have tested them by running the program on terminal.Here is my code :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s=null,file_name,extension;
        int pos = args[0].lastIndexOf(".");

        extension = args[0].substring(pos+1);
        file_name = args[0].substring(0,pos);

        int lang = 0; //  1 -> c,c++ , 2 -> java


        try
        {   

            Process compile = null;

            switch(extension)
            {
                case "c"    :    compile = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gcc -g "+ args[0] + " -o "+file_name+" -lm");
                            lang = 1;           
                            break;
                case "cpp"  :    compile = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("g++ -g "+ args[0] + " -o "+file_name);
                            lang = 1;
                            break;
                case "java" :    compile = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac "+ args[0]);
                            lang = 2;
            }

            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(compile.getErrorStream()));

            if((s = stdError.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Compile Time Error OR Warning : ");

                System.out.println(s);
                while((s = stdError.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }

            double startTime, run_time;
            Process run;

            if(lang == 1)
            {
                 startTime = System.nanoTime();

                 run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./"+file_name+" < "+file_name+"_input.txt > "+file_name+"_output.txt");

                 run_time = (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/(double)Math.pow(10,6);
            }
            else
            {

                startTime = System.nanoTime();

                 run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java "+file_name+" < "+file_name+"_input.txt > "+file_name+"_output.txt");

                 run_time = (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/(double)Math.pow(10,6);
            }



            System.out.println("RunTime : "+ run_time+" ms");

            BufferedReader out_put = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(file_name+"_output.txt")));

            BufferedReader run_stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(run.getErrorStream()));


            if(( s = run_stdError.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Runtime Error : ");

                System.out.println(s);

                while((s = run_stdError.readLine()) != null )
                {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            }
            else if((s = out_put.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String s_string = null;
                int failed = 0;

                File fs = new File(file_name+".txt");

                BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fs));

                if((!s.equals(s_string = br.readLine())))
                {
                    failed = 1;
                }

                while(((s = out_put.readLine()) != null) & ((s_string = br.readLine()) != null) & (failed == 0))
                {
                    if(!s.equals(s_string) )
                    {
                        failed = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if((failed == 1) || s != null || s_string != null)
                {
                    System.out.println("Submmision Failed : ");
                    System.out.println("Either Output Is Wrong.\nOR\nYour Output Is Not According To The Given Format. ");
                    System.exit(0);

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Submission Successful.");
                }

            }
        }   
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Some Error Has Occured : ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When you run this in a debugger and break point it what do you see?  Why is it repeating?

Comment: As an aside: that's a single huge main method making it hard to digest and debug. Consider breaking it down into smaller methods, each one being testable, making your code easier to understand and follow.

Comment: Aside suggestion: I suggest you simplify this line: while(((s = out_put.readLine()) != null) & ((s_string = br.readLine()) != null) & (failed == 0))...

Comment: @Hovercraft  Lets take code after the Run Time has going to be printed.After it i have opened the file where i have saved output 'file_name_output.txt' and if there were any error while execution that will be taken in run_stdError. Now i have used if-else block to either tell the user that there is a error or check the solution of the program.

Comment: @user3190173: I would follow Marko's advice as he's probably got your problem and solution nailed. 1+ to his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Diagnosis

Your program is not in an endless loop, it is *blocking*, and this is the line where it happens:

```
s = run_stdError.readLine()
```

unless there's something on the subprocess's `stderr`, this is going to block until the process dies. However, while waiting here you don't consume the process's `stdout`. It fills its output buffer and blocks.

The result: an interprocess deadlock.

#### Suggested fix

Use a `ProcessBuilder` and use its API to achieve redirection into files with no effort of your own. You have the `redirectOutput(File)` and `redirectError(File)` methods in there.

Comment: can you tell me what should i do to avoid this condition?

Comment: Since you don't want to merge `stdout` with `stderr`, you'll have to use a separate thread which consumes one of them. You could save all `stderr` output in a buffer and display its contents in the end. You could also rely on `gcc`'s return code to decide if there was a problem.

Comment: I am a new guy to Java , whatever you are saying am getting but i do not know how to do it.But you have suggested me another way to solve the problem. I have deleted stderr stream and i have take error too in the out_put file. But also it is not writing anything to file_name_output.txt.....Marko am really sorry but please help me and can you tell me how can i show you my edited code?

Comment: Do this: use a `ProcessBuilder` and use its API to achieve redirection into files with no effort of your own. You have the `redirectOutput(File)` and `redirectError(File)` methods in there.